# Will I get my rank 10 job back?

Tags: the-sims-3

Upon making rank 10 in the military, I noticed i only work once a week. i found a part time job that doesnt make me work on that day. I decided i would try juggling both for some extra cash and so i can work on the other sims in the family a bit more. Turns out the game doesnt let me do both jobs and I lost my progress in the Military. Was curious if i rejoined the military would I be at rank 10 again or would I start over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience, you wouldn't be rank 10, but you wouldn't be rank 1 either. A [forum post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/936498-the-sims-3/50781139) I found (7th down, by *hhhh182*) says you start back at 50% of your previous rank, so in your case, that would be rank 5. I tried to find a reliable wiki source, but unfortunately failed. Other posters share their experience of losing a few ranks after quitting, but not having to start all the way over from rank 1. All pay raises you gained will be lost though.

You can check in the newspaper or on the computer what job title the military is looking for without having to take the job. I don't believe they give the ranks, but here they are with their base pay:

1. Latrine Cleaner (§40/hour)
2. Mess Hall Server (§44/hour)
3. Grunt (§49/hour)
4. Squad Leader (§94/hour)
5. Flight Officer (§108/hour)
6. Wingman (§145/hour)
7. Fighter Pilot (§167/hour)
8. Squadron Leader (§192/hour)
9. Top Gun (§265/hour)
10. Astronaut (§334/hour)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to start over at Rank 1, unfortunately.

Comment: personal experience/wiki-page reference?

Comment: From personal experience I've always had to start off at Rank 1 again. I've never heard of this "50%" of previous rank before. Perhaps it is based upon how long since you left the job?

It looks like from the thread linked by Kareen, you get 50% rank if you immediately get your old job back. I've always waited many days before switching back, which resulted in me starting at Rank 1 again.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get back your rank is to cheat. It sounds bad but it is not actually cheating. What you do is you hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then type in `testingcheatsenabled true`. Then you hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and click on the mailbox. After that, you click set career and go down to Military. Then, you click Astronaut. The same thing happened to me except it was in the Culinary field.